# How to wait a Cell in a Notebook to be executed until another Notebook's Cell expressions executed?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, notebooks

I have two Notebooks and I call the second Notebook from the main but main Notebook's expressions continue executing. I want them to wait until the second Notebook's expressions execution is finished!

My main Notebook's code is such as:

```
docpath = ToFileName[{"C:", "Users"}, "MATHEMATICA"];

nbLBDxi = NotebookOpen[ToFileName[docpath, "LBDxi.nb"]];

SelectionMove[nbLBDxi, All, Notebook];

SelectionEvaluate[nbLBDxi];

NotebookClose[nbLBDxi];
```

- Here the main Notebook's other expressions, which I won't write for brevity, will come but I want them to wait until the above expressions' execution is over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you should use `NotebookEvaluate` instead of `SelectionEvaluate`. According to [the Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookEvaluate.html),

> By default, `NotebookEvaluate` evaluates the cells of a notebook in the
>   same way that `Get` evaluates the lines of a package file.

For example try:

```
nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer[Pause[10]], "Input"]];
NotebookEvaluate[nb]
Print["!"]
```

The `Print["!"]` statement is evaluated only when evaluation of the Notebook `nb` is finished!

Comment: Thank you @Alexey Popkov your reccomendation, using NotebookEvaluate instead of SelectionEvaluate, solved the problem.

Comment: @ahmethasim Then you can [Accept](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer by clicking the green checkmark.