# Evaluate generated notebook and show it when done

Tags: bugs, front-end, programming, notebooks, document-creation

#### Bug introduced in V11.1 or earlier and persists through V11.3

> [CASE:4061569], confirmed

(bug is described below)

### Goal

My goal is the following:

- Create a notebook programmatically, while `Visible->False` is set.
- Evaluate some part of it to generate the output cells.
- When done, show the resulting notebook.

The subject of this question is the second (and partly third point).

### Attempts

My first idea was to use [`SelectionEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectionEvaluate.html) to evaluate the part in question. This has the issue that it does *not* wait for the evaluation to be done, showing the notebook too early. Reading [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119428/36508), it seems there's no way to do what I want using `SelectionEvaluate`.

The next attempt was to use the suggested [`NotebookEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookEvaluate.html). Besides the obvious complication that there is no easy way to only evaluate part of the notebook, I have stumbled across a more severe issue (see below).

### Question

What is the best way to achieve my goal? urrently, I'm thinking about tagging all the cells I want evaluated and the use the tag based filtering of `NotebookEvaluate`. While being extremely inconvenient, this also suffers from the issue below. Ideally, I would prefer something more equivalent to `SelectionEvaluate` + "wait for it to be done" than this.

### Issue with `NotebookEvaluate`

The following is an attempt to generate a notebook, evaluate it, and then show the result:

```
nb = CreateNotebook[Visible -> False]
(* NotebookObject[...] *)

NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Unevaluated[1 + 2], "Input"]]

NotebookGet@nb
(* Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"1", "+", "2"}]], "Input"]}, 
 WindowSize -> {775, 872}, 
 WindowMargins -> {{564, Automatic}, {Automatic, 74}}, 
 Visible -> False, 
 FrontEndVersion -> "11.3 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 6, 2018)", 
 StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"] *)

NotebookEvaluate[nb]
(* 3 *)

(* doesn't do anything *)
SetOptions[nb, Visible -> True]

NotebookGet@nb
(* Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"1", "+", "2"}]], "Input", CellLabel -> "In[1]:="]},
 WindowSize -> {775, 872}, 
 WindowMargins -> {{564, Automatic}, {Automatic, 74}}, 
 Visible -> True, 
 FrontEndVersion -> "11.3 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 6, 2018)", 
 StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"] *)

(* displays the notebook successfully *)
NotebookPut@NotebookGet@nb
(* NotebookObject[...] *)
```

Something about `NotebookEvaluate` causes the notebook to be permanently invisible (I assume this is a bug?).

- Note that making the notebook visible before calling `NotebookEvaluate` works as expected
- `NotebookPut@*NotebookGet` fixes the issue, but is of course ugly and
  breaks any state (selections, other references to the
  `NotebookObject`,...) that was present before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround, the idea is to extract cells you need, evaluate them in separate notebooks and insert results back.

The limitation is that it does not handle output cells that already exist for input you want to evaluate. You may want to grab them too or delete generated cells via token or something.

```
nb = CreateDocument[{
    ExpressionCell[Defer[1 + 1], "Input"],
    ExpressionCell[Defer[2 + 1], "Input"],
       (*multiline cell*)
    Cell[BoxData[{MakeBoxes[1 + 1], MakeBoxes[1 + 2]}], "Input"]
}, Visible -> False];
```

And the procedure:

```
cells = Cells[nb, CellStyle -> {"Input"}][[{1, 3}]]
Scan[
 Module[{cell, nb, result, sourceCell, sourceNb}
 , sourceCell = #;
   sourceNb = ParentNotebook @ sourceCell;
   cell = NotebookRead @ sourceCell;
   nb = NotebookPut @ Notebook[{cell}, Visible -> False];
   NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True];
   result = NotebookGet[nb][[1]];
   SelectionMove[sourceCell, All, Cell];
   NotebookWrite[sourceNb, result];
   NotebookClose[nb];
 ] &,
 cells
]

SetOptions[nb, Visible -> True];
SetSelectedNotebook[nb];
```

The 3rd problem does not apply because it is not the original notebook which was evaluated. I'd report the visibility problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! Using a separate notebook to do this should actually simplify several less-than-ideal workarounds for some of the other issues I've encountered - and none of the limitations you've pointed out should matter in my case (lucky me, for once at least )