# how to run a .nb file

Tags: notebooks

I have a code like this:

```
namep = StringJoin[name, ".pdf"]; 
nb1 = NotebookOpen[alg];
SelectionMove[nb1, All, Notebook];
FrontEndTokenExecute[nb1, "EvaluateNotebook"];
Do[Print[TabView[{datos -> grad[[i]], Graficos -> graf[[i]], 
Correlaciones -> grac}]], {i, diamindd, diamaxdd, step}];
```

But the Do instruction begins when the nb1 is still working and the print does not produce any:
Part::partd: Part specification grad[[1]] is longer than depth of object.

How I can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can adapt this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119422/how-to-wait-a-cell-in-a-notebook-to-be-executed-until-another-notebooks-cell-ex

Comment: Now I have:   nb1 = NotebookOpen[alg];
                       NotebookEvaluate[nb1];
                       Do[Print[TabView[{datos -> grad[[i]], Graficos -> graf[[i]], 
     Correlaciones -> grac}]], {i, diamindd, diamaxdd, step}];                but the program un the notebook and remains evaluating with no answer. Only I have answer if I write the Print in a separate cell. Thanks